# Entangled electrons seem impossible

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electrons, quantum-entanglement, fermions

Two fermions cannot share the same quantum state.

But two electrons can be entangled. Entangled electrons share the same quantum state.

Thus a contradiction.

Where is my error?

Comment: Your error is in the sentence "Entangled electrons share the same quantum state".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The claim *"Entangled electrons share the same quantum state"* is not correct. In an entangled state there is no well-defined notion of the states of the individual components, this is the very definition of an entangled state:

A composite state $\chi\in\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_2$ is called *entangled*, if it cannot be written as $\chi=\psi\otimes\phi$ for $\psi\in\mathcal{H}_1,\phi\in\mathcal{H}_2$.

The composite states forbidden by the Pauli exclusion principle, however, are states of the form $\psi\otimes\psi\in\mathcal{H}$ for the same $\psi\in\mathcal{H}$, where both particles have the same space of states $\mathcal{H}$.

Thus, there is no contradiction.

Answer (score 2):

I am no expert, but I think looking up [Quantum entanglement](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement) on Wikipedia will tell you that the entangled particles are in correlated states, but that is not the same as sharing the same state.

Also, as a side issue,  two electrons cannot have the same 4 quantum numbers, **if** they are bound to an atom, but this does not apply to free electrons.